# getting crash om memory set After updating to lion and xCode

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, c, xcode

I have just updated to Lion and now my app is crashing which was working fine in older version. It crash on memset function with no logs.

```
unsigned char *theValue;
add(theValue, someotherValues);
```

I have passed theValue reference to function

```
add(unsigned char *inValue, some other perameter) {
memset(inValue,0,sizeOf(inValue)); // **here it is crashing**
}
```

Comment: What does `theValue` point to? Also, even if it's pointing to something reasonable, the code doesn't make sense; you're trying to set the char(s) that the pointer `theValue` points to, but using the size of the pointer itself to determine how much memory to set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there really no code between the declaration of `theValue` and the call to `add()`? If so, then that's your problem. You are passing a random value as the first parameter to `memset()`.

For this code to make sense, you have to allocate a block of memory for `theValue` and pass its size to `add()`, like so:

```
unsigned char *theValue = new unsigned char[BUFSIZE]; // Or malloc
add(theValue, BUFSIZE, ...);

void add(unsigned char *inValue, size_t bufsize, ...) {
    memset(inValue, 0, bufsize);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you allocate memory for inValue?

1)

```
add(unsigned char *inValue, some other perameter) {
    inValue = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(inValue));
    memset(inValue,0,sizeOf(inValue)); // **here it is crashing**
}
```

2)

```
theValue = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(inValue));
add(theValue, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned char *theValue;
```

This points to a random bit of memory (or 0). Until you call `malloc` you don't own what it's pointing at so you can't really memset it.

Comment: Just started with the first problem I saw; figured we would deal with any others as he ran into them :)